# Latest Ripple not working with phonegap (works with Cordova)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ripple

I'm trying to use the latest Apache Ripple mobile device emulator with PhoneGap + Sencha Touch. Works ok with a Cordova app but not with PhoneGap.

**Observations**

- Reports that it detects a 'Cordova 3.0 Project' that is actually a PhoneGap project
- Failed to find that does not exist for either PhoneGap or Cordova projects:

  - 'd:\Learn\PhoneGap\weatherapp\phonegap\platforms\android\assets\www\platforms'
- This directory **does** exist

  - d:\Learn\PhoneGap\weatherapp\phonegap\platforms\android\assets\www\

**Full Log**

```
INFO: Server instance running on: http://localhost:4400
INFO: CORS XHR proxy service on: http://localhost:4400/ripple/xhr_proxy
INFO: JSONP XHR proxy service on: http://localhost:4400/ripple/jsonp_xhr_proxy
Cordova 3.0 Project detected...

fs.js:654
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path));
             ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory   'd:\Learn\PhoneGap\weatherapp\phonegap\platforms\android\assets\www\platforms'
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
at buildPaths (c:\Users\tohagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\server\emulate\cordovaProject.js:11:28)
at Object.module.exports.inject (c:\Users\tohagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\server\emulate\cordovaProject.js:38:21)
at Object.module.exports.start (c:\Users\tohagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\server\emulate.js:60:32)
at Object.self.start (c:\Users\tohagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\cli\emulate.js:30:27)
at Object.self.call (c:\Users\tohagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\cli\emulate.js:27:14)
at lookup (c:\Users\tohagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\cli\index.js:43:20)
at Object.module.exports.interpret (c:\Users\tohagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\lib\cli\index.js:58:13)
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\tohagan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple-emulator\bin\ripple:22:25)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix by following these steps http://johnreid.it/2012/06/23/get-ripple-to-work-in-linux/.

I found a little strange at first, but decided ...

Comment: This article was posted in 2012 and it's using an older version of Ripple based on a Chrome plugin. The latest Ripple version I'm using doesn't use a plugin.  I'm also trying to get this working on Windows not Linux though I suspect that the solution I'm after will just be tweaking paths somewhere so is probably platform neutral.

Comment: Here's an intro to the latest Ripple:
  http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/5/Ripple-is-Reborn